# Cell height same as TableView height on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

I need to **swipe between the images vertically**, but I need to view **only one image at time** on display. So I need the **Cell height** same as **Table View height** on **every device**. The Table View is **not full-screened**.

How can I obtain this? I need to check **Scrolling: Paging Enabled** feature in Table View to swipe between those pictures, but when the row sizes are different, the swiping is not working.

Thanks you for any advice. :)

Here is the screen of my **table view** in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: can you please post some code here so I will help you.

Comment: The screen of my storyboard with not full screened table view have been added to question description.